# RxJS Observables: why does callback fire twice?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

Consider this code, from an Angular 6 component:

```
class AppComponent  {
  subject = new Subject<any>();
  one = this.subject.pipe(share(), tap(e => log('one emits')));
  two = this.one.pipe(tap(e => log('two emits')));
  three = this.one.pipe(delay(500), tap(e => log('three emits')));

  ngOnInit() {
    this.two.subscribe(e => log('two received'));
    this.three.subscribe(e => log('three received'));    
    this.subject.next();
  }  
}
```

When `ngOnInit` executes, this is what gets logged:

> one emits
>
> two emits
>
> two received
>
> one emits
>
> three emits
>
> three received

I don't understand: why does `one` emit twice? Shouldn't the `share` operator in its pipe make `two` and `three` subscribe to the same shared source?

[Source on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xoyvw6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `share()` operator multicasts at the point you use it. So when you use it before `tap` then `tap` still has two observers.

So just use `share` after `tap` and it'll maintain one subscription to its parent.

```
one = this.subject.pipe(tap(e => console.log('one emits')), share());
```